# Superfluous space in Android widget

Tags: android, android-widget

When developing an Android home screen widget, I ran into a strange problem of having the widget boundaries expand beyond the widget layout itself. You can see what I mean in the screenshot below:

[image]

However, when I resize, the boundaries fit perfectly:

[image]

I've played with `minWidth` and `minHeight` values, but that does not have any effect. Here's the layout of the widget:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_remember"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorHeaderBlue"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/cardview_side_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/cardview_side_padding"
        android:paddingStart="22dp"
        android:paddingEnd="22dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="@color/textColorSecondary"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="@string/remember_header"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget_remember_words"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorSearchSuggestionsList">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_remember"
            android:text="test"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorPrimary"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cardview_side_padding"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/cardview_side_padding"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_remember_yes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/yes"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="14dp"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/text_remember"
            android:textColor="@color/colorHeaderBlue"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_remember_no"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/no"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="14dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@id/text_remember_yes"
            android:layout_below="@id/text_remember"
            android:layout_marginEnd="14dp"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/widget_remember_no_words"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@color/colorSearchSuggestionsList"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_no_words"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/no_words_available"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorHint"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_remember_reload"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/try_again"
            android:layout_below="@id/text_no_words"
            android:textColor="@color/textColorHint"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And configuration file in `xml` folder:

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/appwidget_remember"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen">
</appwidget-provider>
```

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting to see instead? It seems to be working correctly.

If the size of your widget contents is smaller than the outer bounds, the unoccupied space is simply transparent. That's as-designed. Your root container doesn't have a `layout_gravity` attribute, thus it is centered (vertically) by default.

If you want something different, try changing your LinearLayout's `layout_gravity` value (to something like `top` or `bottom`), or try setting your layout to `layout_height="match_parent"` along with something like `background="@color/red"` (so that the empty space is no longer transparent).